Changing CollectionView layout stretches each item to width of screen
I am trying to make a "See more" button display more, or less items. "Less" is defined as a horizontal list displaying multiple items at a time, whilst "More" is a vertical 2 column grid that takes up the entire screen. The initial starting layout is fine on bootup and displays multiple items,  however when I expand and make it vertical, and then back to horiztonal, all items occupy significantly more space.
The XAML I tried for the CollectionView:
<CollectionView
    ItemsSource="{Binding FoodPlace}"
    x:Name="CollectionviewFoodplaces"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
    SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="foodgrid" RowDefinitions="100,50" ColumnDefinitions="150" MaximumWidthRequest="150">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                       x:Name="Icon_"
                       WidthRequest="150"
                       Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Margin="2"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Path=Pin.Label}" 
                       x:Name="Labell"
                       Grid.Row="1" 
                       Margin="2" 
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       FontSize="Body" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       WidthRequest="150"
                       Grid.Column="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

The codebehind for the button to switch between more and less:
 public static GridItemsLayout seemorelayout = new GridItemsLayout(2, ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical);
...
...
...
 private void buttonFoodplaceSeeMore_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     SeeMoreFood = !SeeMoreFood;
     if (SeeMoreFood == true)
     {
         buttonFoodplaceSeeMore.Text = "See Less <";
         CollectionviewFoodplaces.ItemsLayout = seemorelayout;

     }
     if (SeeMoreFood == false)
     {
         buttonFoodplaceSeeMore.Text = "See More >";
         CollectionviewFoodplaces.ItemsLayout = LinearItemsLayout.Horizontal;

     }
 }


I test the code you provided and it works well. Here is the effect.

Is this the effect bother before and after toggling the button? Thanks!

Yes, it’s the gif I recorded. And here is the code.

Thats odd, I guess it must be something else causing my problem. Thanks for looking into it

Well, I put the code in the answer below and you can try it :)

My environment is VS2022 17.10.0 | .NET 8
Model and ViewModel:
namespace MauiApp2.ViewModels
{
    public class Monkey
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsModified { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MauiApp2.ViewModels
{
    public class MonkeysViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys { get; set; }
 
        public MonkeysViewModel()
        {
            CreateMonkeys();
        }
        void CreateMonkeys()
        {
            Monkeys = new ObservableCollection<Monkey>
            {
                new Monkey() { Name = "suma", IsModified = false },
                new Monkey() { Name = "demo", IsModified = false },
                new Monkey() { Name = "duff", IsModified = false },
                new Monkey() { Name = "cume", IsModified = false }
            };
        }
 
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

Page and Page Code behind:
<ContentPage ....
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.NewPage1"
             Title="NewPage1">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MonkeysViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Button Text="See More >"
                x:Name="buttonFoodplaceSeeMore"
                Clicked="buttonFoodplaceSeeMore_Clicked"/>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        x:Name="CollectionviewFoodplaces" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="foodgrid" RowDefinitions="100,50" ColumnDefinitions="150" MaximumWidthRequest="150">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                       x:Name="Icon_"
                       WidthRequest="150" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                       Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Red"
                       Margin="2"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       x:Name="Labell"
                       Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" 
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Body" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="150"
                       Grid.Column="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public static GridItemsLayout seemorelayout = new GridItemsLayout(2, ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical);
    private bool SeeMoreFood=false;
 
    public NewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 
    private void buttonFoodplaceSeeMore_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SeeMoreFood = !SeeMoreFood;
        if (SeeMoreFood == true)
        {
            buttonFoodplaceSeeMore.Text = "See Less <";
            CollectionviewFoodplaces.ItemsLayout = seemorelayout;
 
        }
        if (SeeMoreFood == false)
        {
            buttonFoodplaceSeeMore.Text = "See More >";
            CollectionviewFoodplaces.ItemsLayout = LinearItemsLayout.Horizontal;
 
        }
    }
}

